# How to configure an IIS re-write rule with specific pattern?

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, iis-10

I am trying to create a URL rewrite rule to send any url that ends with a specific 2-character string (case-insensitive) to a different url.

For example, I want these to match:

```
http://www.foo.com/mn  
http://www.foodev.com/mn  
http://www.foo.com/MN  
http://www.foodev.com/MN
```

But these to fail:

```
http://www.foo.com/la/mn  
http://www.foo.com/la/di/da/mn  
http://www.foodev.com/la/mn  
http://www.foodev.com/la/di/da/mn
```

I set up the following rule:

```
    <rule name="Redirect MN" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true"  />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/\/mn$/gmi" />
     </conditions>        
      <action type="Redirect" url="https//www.foo.com/mn" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Where I'm using the {PATH_INFO} value with the pattern `/\/mn$/gmi` which seems like it should match: https://regex101.com/r/ql2USW/1/

When I view the event in the FREBUI viewer, I see the expanded input and the pattern (which appear to be correct), but it does not succeed.

```
Input {PATH_INFO} 
ExpandedInput /MN 
MatchType Pattern 
Pattern /\/mn$/gmi 
Negate false 
Succeeded false
```

How should I change the configuration of this rule?

[image: Screenshot of the FREBUI]

Microsoft-IIS/10.0

Comment: @Emma I thought about it but the tag activity in SO is higher than it is in server fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, we could solve this problem. Let's start with a simple expression to pass our desired URLs and fail the undesired ones. Later, if we wish, we can restrict it with additional boundaries.

Here, this expression would likely match the desired URLs by simply removing the `$` char:

```
\.com\/mn
```

And I'm hoping that the problem might be solved here.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qXl63w/1)

We could though continue adding boundaries such as, one in the left of `.com`:

```
.+\.com\/mn
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OkefXh/1)

Or similar to your original version, we can add start and end boundaries:

```
^.+\.com\/mn$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CBBi2z/1)

Then, our setup might likely look like:

```
<rule name="Redirect MN" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true"  />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="\.com\/mn/gmi" />
    </conditions>        
    <action type="Redirect" url="https//www.foo.com/mn" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Or any other pattern that we wish to change would likely goes here:

```
pattern="\.com\/mn/gmi"
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CBBi2z/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

Comment: The input to the condition is only the path ( without domain). So it always starts with a forward slash.

Comment: I did get it to work by removing the global flags ( I think). I don't understand why it works.  I think your answer would work on the full url: HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL instead of PATH_INFO.   I'll post what worked when I guess back to my computer.

Comment: btw, that https://jex.im site is cool! definitely bookmarking that one!

Answer (score 0):

I am posting what worked for me which is close to what I already had. I removed the global flags (including the case-insensitive flag).

Now the rule matches and even ignores case, which is what I wanted.  I don't understand why it works since the pattern should only match lower case. Perhaps the conditions inherit the "ignoreCase" attribute of the rule it applies to?  I'm new to working with  URL Rewrite Module, so someone else probably knows how it all works.

```xml
    <rule name="Redirect MN" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true"  />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="(\/mn$)" />
     </conditions>        
      <action type="Redirect" url="https//www.foo.com/mn" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```